# Backup and restore core data model FILE in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

It seems it's not easy to sync CoreData entries with Cloudkit.

So I wonder if it is possible to backup the entire .xcdatamodeld **file** in the user iCloud storage and then the user can restore the file by pressing a button.

Is it possible ?

Comment: `iCloud ubiquity container` is possible but deprecated and iCloud Drive **is** CloudKit.

Comment: @vadian thx, I updated the terms for a better comprehension

Comment: You cannot save the physical file but you can save the model (the CoreData entities, attributes and relationships). But you're right, it's not easy.

Comment: @vadian have you tried? got an example? i believe it is not a single file, especially if you version it. but the idea itself is sure quite interesting!

Comment: @MaximVolgin Technically you do can save the `.xcdatamodeld` file, it's a bundle containing an XML file but you cannot use it in CloudKit. You have to write code to keep the CoreData database and CloudKit in sync

Comment: @vadian i know, my hypothetical use case would be recreating the entire CoreData DB from scratch upon an update from Cloud. Keeping data in sync is rather straightforward if using RxCloudKit/RxCoreData, and if the uniqueness constraints are the same in both CK and CD.